# wp_enqueue_script does not load in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have this simple plugin I am making for WordPress, and I am unable to import a simple test javascript. I am lost.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Hey, what are you doing here? Silly Human. Scripts are for grown ups');

if (!function_exists('add_action') ) {
    echo "Hey, you can\t access this file, you silly human.";
    exit;
}


class SimplePlugin {

    public function __construct($arg) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'test1') );
    }

    function activate() { 

    }

    function deactivate() { 

    }

    function uninstall() { 

    } 

public function test1() { 
    wp_deregister_script('my-plugin');
    wp_register_script( 'my-plugin', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'test.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin');

}




}





if (class_exists( 'MySweetEddPlugin') ) {
    $MySweetEddPlugin = new MySweetEddPlugin('');  //We now run all things in construct


}

//Activate
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($MySweetEddPlugin, 'activate'));

//Deactivate
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($MySweetEddPlugin, 'deactivate'));
```

The class name is more unique in my file and Before you suggest, a slash may be missing/extra. I've tried it with and without slashes, trying it with it completely written out, and it's the wierdest thing. It'll Show the file has been included with the incorrect urls, but never the correct url. If i just say

```
wp_register_script( 'my-plugin', '/test.js' );
```

it'll include that js file (non existing js file). However it won't include it when it's correct. It's like it preventing me from including correct files? is there something am missing about WordPress plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. It was the plugin Fast Velocity Minify that was causing it not to include the file. When i deactivated it, the file immediately showed up. When i reactivated the file remain there, however any update i made to the file will not show up until I deactivate and reactivate the plugins. As always as soon as i post on here, i figure it out.